# Focal Loss in RetinaNet

Tags: computer-vision

Can someone please explain in simple what is focal loss in RetinaNet
from this below 2 paper
Feature Pyramid Networks for Object Detection
Focal loss for Dense object detection

Comment: Someone please help on this

Comment: Someone please help on this

Comment: see this Medium post: https://medium.com/@14prakash/the-intuition-behind-retinanet-eb636755607d

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The focal loss can be defined as (Note: the original paper described the loss for binary classification, but here I extended it for the multi-class case):

[image]

where `K` denotes the number of classes; `yi` equals 1 if the ground-truth belongs to the i-th class and 0 otherwise; `pi` is the predicted probability for the i-th class; `γ∈(0,+∞)` is a focusing parameter; `αi∈[0,1]` is a weighting parameter for the i-th class. The loss is similar to categorical cross entropy, and they would be equivalent if `γ=0` and `αi=1`. So, what are the purposes of these two additional parameters?

As the original paper points out, class imbalance is a very problematic issue that limits the performance of detectors in practice. This is because most locations in an image are easy negatives (meaning that they can be easily classified by the detector as background) and contribute no useful learning signal; worse still, since they account for a large portion of inputs, they can overwhelm the loss and computed gradients and lead to degenerated models. To address this problem, the focal loss introduces the focusing parameter `γ` to down-weight the loss assigned to easily classified examples. This effect increases as value of `γ` increases and makes the network focus more on hard examples.

The balancing parameter `α` is also useful for addressing class imbalance. It may be set by inverse class frequency (or as a hyper-parameter) so that the loss  assigned to examples of the background class can be down-weighted.

Note that since the two parameters interact with each other, they should be selected together. Generally speaking, as `γ` is increased, α should be decreased slightly11.

Here is a post that explains RetinaNet in greater details: [https://blog.zenggyu.com/en/post/2018-12-05/retinanet-explained-and-demystified/](https://blog.zenggyu.com/en/post/2018-12-05/retinanet-explained-and-demystified/#fnref10)

Comment: What does "ground-truth" mean in this context?
Here is a definition of ground-truth,
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17839/what-is-ground-truth
The responses suggest that the ground-truth is equivalent to "labels". Though, I'm not sure if this is the case here.